# Textformfield focus change in other widgets on instant

Tags: flutter

Using a textformfield widget, I need to change the color in the background according to the focus and unfocus status, but this change does not change on the screen at the time of focus and unfocus.
Below is a code sample.

Here it is;

```
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

Container(
   width: double.infinity,
   color: _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
   child: TextFormField(
             focusNode: _focusNode,
          ),
)
```

Comment: do you update the state with setState(() {}) ?

Comment: If I check the status with setState(()) the keyboard closes I guess I'm not using this correctly. Where should I call setState()?

Comment: wait I will write ana nswer

Answer (score 0):

try another approach of doing it, by adding a listener on the `FocusNode` in the `StatefullWidget` that will change the color based on it:

First, in you're `State` object:

```
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  Color _color = Colors.red;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(
      () {
        if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
          setState(() {
            _color = Colors.green;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _color = Colors.red;
          });
        }
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

this will listen to the `FocusNode`, when it has to focus it will update the color to green, otherwise, it's red.

Then in the widget:

```
   Container(
   width: double.infinity,
   color: _color,
   child: TextFormField(
             focusNode: _focusNode,
          ),
)
```

Comment: Same problem. Color changes in this state but keyboard closes in setState

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueNotifier`

```
 ValueNotifier<bool> isFocused = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
 FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(
      () {
        if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
          isFocused.value = true;
        } else {
          isFocused.value = false;
        }
      },
    );
  }

//Your Widget
 ValueListenableBuilder(
     valueListenable: isFocused,
     builder: (context, mobile, child) {
          return Container(
             width: double.infinity,
             color: isFocused.value ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
             child: TextFormField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
              ),
          );
       },
   ),
```